# Recommended Ubuntu Linux kernel version to use for CXL 1.1 and CXL 2.0 enumeration?

Tags: drivers, 22.04, workflow

We are using ubuntu 22.04.3 with kernel version 6.2.34 and currently 6.6-rc7 too.
I can observer the CXL driver files inside the **driver** and **misc** folder while exploring the kernel directories.
Hence, can we assume that CXL 1.1 is supported in the kernel?

- Please suggest the recommended kernel versions to use for working with CXL 1.1 device. (we were suggested by someone to just use mainline kernel version)
- can we get the enumeration process/flow of a CXL 1.1 device from the
  kernel source code? (what could be the flow?)          if no, then how
  can    we use the present code from kernel, to detect or enumerate or
  perform read/write    operations on the CXL 1.1 device ? (please
  suggest if any utility app or knowledge    resource is available for
  this. Currently we are using CXL specification document **1.1** and **3.0**)
- I have also accidentally deleted an **initrd.img** file from a customised kernel
  (eg. initrd.img-6.4-smdk), so can i insert **initrd.img** from a normal kernel source(eg. 6.4.x)

Please suggest modifications or if any other information would be required to help get assistance.
Thank you